# how to write a json array for ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

```
var obj = { subjects: [{ area: "Math"}, {area: "English"}] }

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"mydata": JSON.stringify(obj)},
  url: '/tosubjects',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  statusCode: {
     200:function() { alert("200"); },
     202:function() { alert("202"); }
  },
  success: function() {  alert("sent"); },
  error: function(xhr){  alert("error: " + xhr.statusText);       
  }        
});
```

with

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

in my form helper. I'm using Rails.

This works fine with single records. But, as above, when trying to pass two records as a json array, I get the error:

```
 JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"
```

This is because of the way I have written

```
data: {"mydata": JSON.stringify(obj)},
```

When I write this as:

data: `JSON.stringify(obj)`,

there is no error, but then I have no way to assign a name to the object, such as `params[:mydata]`.

How does the `data:` field need to be written?

Comment: `data : obj` comes to mind? No need to stringify!

Comment: Thanks. You are right about stringify. But...i had to rewrite obj as, var obj = '{ "subjects": [{ "area": "Math"}, {"area": "English"}] }'

Answer (score 0):

This worked. But if there is a better way...please !

```
var obj = { subjects: [{ area: "Math"}, {area: "English"}] }

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data : JSON.stringify(obj),
  url: '/tosubjects',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  statusCode: {
     200:function() { alert("200"); },
     202:function() { alert("202"); }
  },
  success: function() {  alert("sent"); },
  error: function(xhr){  alert("error: " + xhr.statusText); }        
});
```

In the controller,

```
ar = params[:subjects]

ar.each do |obj|
   subject = Subject.new(obj)
   if subject.save
    #
   else
    #
   end
end

respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json { 
        render :json => @subject
      }
end
```